# Is it there a better way to Search HashMap from ArrayList

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to implement Searching in `ListView`. My `ListView` is comprised of `HashMap` in `ArrayList` and I managed to implement the logic but I guess there is much object and memory allocation in my approach each time the text change. Therefore I am looking for less memory allocated logic to search in my `ListView` with `HashMap` in `ArrayList`

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            //textlength = searchBar.getText().length();
            //text_sort.clear();
            sortedArrayList.clear();


            for (int i = 0; i < myHistList.size(); i++) {

                HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                hash = myHistList.get(i);

                if (hash.get("myName").toLowerCase().indexOf(searchBar.getText().toString().toLowerCase()) != -1) {

                    String callerNum1 = hash.get("myNumber");
                    String myName1 = hash.get("myName");


                    HashMap<String, String> searchedHash = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    searchedHash.put("myNumber", callerNum1);
                    searchedHash.put("myName", myName1);
                    recordingFile1);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    sortedArrayList.add(searchedHash);

                }
            }

            ListView actualLv = mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView();
            actualLv.setAdapter(new myHistoryListAdapter(myHistory.this, sortedArrayList));

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you can replace

```
HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
hash = myHistList.get(i);
```

with just

```
 HashMap<String, String> hash = myHistList.get(i);
```

It will slightly reduce the number of redundant objects.

At second step if you need to compare strings are the same but ignore letters' case you can try to simplify your `if` condition

```
if (hash.get("myName").toLowerCase().indexOf(searchBar.getText().toString().toLowerCase()) != -1)
```

with

```
if(hash.get("myName").compareToIgnoreCase(searchBar.getText().toString()) == 0)
```

Also if you put the `String callerNum1 = hash.get("myNumber");` above the `if` statement then you can save some time because you don't need to look through your HashSet two times to search the same element. It will look like following:

```
String callerNum1 = hash.get("myNumber");

if(callerNum1.compareToIgnoreCase(searchBar.getText().toString()) == 0){
     ...
}
```