# Search the values in Arraylist of HashMap

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to search, track name from arraylist of hashmap. I have searched lots of sites on this, but couldn't get any solution.

Here is the code for creating Arraylist of hash maps:

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);

  //Count from the server
  int count = dataCount();

  for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) 
    {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // adding data to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, trackNumber);
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, trackTitle);
        map.put(KEY_ARTIST, trackArtist);
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, trackDuration);
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, trackAlbumArt);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);

    }

    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

On TextChanged I am trying to get the search results and update the adapter with new results.

I was trying out similar logic that was given in

[HashMap Searching For A Specific Value in Multiple Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381968/hashmap-searching-for-a-specific-value-in-multiple-keys)

[Is it there a better way to Search HashMap from ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951854/is-it-there-a-better-way-to-search-hashmap-from-arraylist)

But couldn't get any results.

Thanks!

Comment: Which value you want to be able to search by ? (KEY_ID/KEY_TITLE/...)

Comment: I would like get Key_title value

Comment: How perfect do you want? For this kind of data structure, there is only one solution is iterate maps in songsList and do your search. If you have performance issue, you need to change your data structure.

Comment: @Loc Ha : I don't have any solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**: Iterate the list items and search for a match:

```
// this code wasn't tested - but I'm sure you'll get the idea
Map getSong(String title) {
    for(Map song : songsList) {
        if(song.get(KEY_TITLE).equals(title)) {
            return song;
        }
    }
    return Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

**Option 2** (preferred): save the songs into another Map (instead of a list) and use the title as the "key":

```
Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();

// add a song:
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(KEY_ID, trackNumber);
map.put(KEY_TITLE, trackTitle);
map.put(KEY_ARTIST, trackArtist);
map.put(KEY_DURATION, trackDuration);
map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, trackAlbumArt);
// adding HashList to Map
songsList.put(trackTitle, map);
```

then you don't have to iterate a list to find your song, but simply do:

```
Map getSong(String title) {
    return songsList.get(title);
}
```

Comment: With Option 2: The problem is I am showing the list songs, artist,Duration, Album in a listview using customAdaptor. If I change to Maps then how will I fetch the data to show it in listview?  title.setText(song.get(Songview.KEY_TITLE));?

Comment: For your first comment, the values of the Map can be converted to a list easily: `List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(songsList.values());`

Comment: As for your second comment, I think I understand the issue - see code changes above

Comment: For Option 1: Now it is returning empty.

Comment: @TheDevMan run a debugger and add a breakpoint in the `if` condition to see why it fails. Sorry I can't help you debug.

Comment: I am getting the results. It is working fine now with Option 1 but how do I add them to my list to show in my listView.

Comment: I tried the following: songsList.add(map);   adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);                list.setAdapter(adapter); but I end up getting force with the following error log: http://justpaste.it/ggr4

Comment: @TheDevMan this exception means that you're changing the list while iterating it. There could be 3 solutions for that: either don't iterate it while you're changing it. Don't change it while iterating it or create a copy of the list and iterate the copy while you're modifying the original list.

Comment: I have iterrate to get the results. If I don't change the results then how to show the results value in my listview?

Comment: If you need to change more than one item it means "batch update" - create a new list with all the new results and have the adapter load the new list.

Comment: Yeah. That is what I doing.. I am create new ArrayList naming to SongResults and then doing the same stuff similar to code in my question. I am still getting same error.

Comment: @TheDevMan please post a *new* question with the relevant code and mark the line where you're getting the error + post a full stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have created a new question on setting part. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088932/update-search-results-to-lazy-adapter-in-android