# Update Search Results to Lazy Adapter in android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have list of Item and would like to implement the search feature for it. Hence, I have a text box with addTextChangedListener to it.

The search Results are coming fine, but when I try to set the results to ListView the new results are getting appended to old results.

I am using a Lazy Adapter. How do I clear the old results from my adapter?

Below is the code:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> searchResults = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);

 //Count from the server 
 int count = dataCount();

for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) 
{
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // adding data to HashMap key => value
    map.put(KEY_ID, trackNumber);
    map.put(KEY_TITLE, trackTitle);
    map.put(KEY_ARTIST, trackArtist);
    map.put(KEY_DURATION, trackDuration);
    map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, trackAlbumArt);

    // adding HashList to ArrayList
    songsList.add(map);

}

adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

TextWatcher

```
 nameText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {

            getSong(s);
        }

    });
```

For getting results:

```
  Map getSong(CharSequence s) 
  {

    for (HashMap<String, String> map : songsList)
    {
        if(map.get(KEY_TITLE).contains(s))
        {
            Log.e("Map","Son"+map);

            HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map2.put(KEY_ID, map.get(KEY_ID));
            map2.put(KEY_TITLE, map.get(KEY_TITLE));
            map2.put(KEY_ARTIST, map.get(KEY_ARTIST));
            map2.put(KEY_DURATION, map.get(KEY_DURATION));
            map2.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, map.get(KEY_THUMB_URL));

            searchResults.add(map2);            
        }
    }

    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, searchResults);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return Collections.emptyMap();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `songsList2` is supposed to be `searchResults` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not "cleaning" old search results before you begin.

Add the following line:

```
searchResults = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

in the beginning of the method `getSong()` (before the for-loop)

Comment: thanks but miss matching, search is good but when clicking the element it opens in other item

Comment: @Prasad you have a different issue - post a new question with all the relevant information